# PHP call for Oracle Procedure

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures

My client has oracle system and im asked to call a oracle procedure with following instruction.

*Parameter you’re calling (ec_erp_pkg.request_order) should consider the new extra parameters*
[image]

*Please also note, returned record type has added the price in it.*

[image]

*You can try p_customer_number = ‘7800’
Item can use RB-110H and VRH2009-153 with any quantity.*

Following is my code so far.

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$CRMDB59 =
  "(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xx.xxx.xxx.xxx)(PORT = xxx))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = xxxxx.xxxx.xxx.xx)
    )
  )";

$conn = oci_connect("more","more4ec",$CRMDB59);
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
    echo "Successfully connected!";
}

$cn = '7800';
$cp = 'RB-110H';

$sql = "BEGIN ec_erp_pkg.request_order(:cn, :cp); END;";

//Run a sample query
$s = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

/* Binding Parameters */
oci_bind_by_name($s, ':cn', $cn) ;
oci_bind_by_name($s, ':cp', $cp) ;

$res = oci_execute($s);

print_r($s);

?>
```

But it gives me following error.

"Successfully connected!"
"oci_execute(): ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'REQUEST_ORDER' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7"

Can anyone tell me how to call this in php in right way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I am reading this correctly you need three arguments. You're only sending 2.

Comment: he said The 3rd parameter is also a table type. im not sure what i should include to this. do u have any idea?

Comment: The 3d parameter is the output variable where you'll get your result.